# How to tell if an Array or List is also a set?

Tags: java

I have a `char[]`. I would like to be able to tell if it is a `Set` and if so create a new `Set` with the array values. I know I can use a `try-catch` block but is there any built in method for Java which I could use to test this without throwing an error. It is not imperative that I use a `char[]`. I could also use a List or something else.

Comment: Please give a further explanation of your problem. Why would you want to check if a `char[]` is a `Set`?

Comment: I have a char[] and I need a way to test if there are duplicate elements.

Comment: Then JonSkeet spotted the problem and provided a great explanation to solve this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I have a char[]. I would like to be able to tell if it is a Set

It won't be. It can't be. It may have distinct values, but it *won't* be a `Set`.

If you actually want to check whether the array contains distinct values, the simplest way would probably be to create a `Set<Character>` and check whether any `add` operation returns `false`:

```
public static boolean uniqueValues(char[] values) {
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();
    for (char c : values) {
        if (!set.add(c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

(That gives you an early out as soon as you find a duplicate, rather than continuing to construct the whole set.)

An alternative would be to create a `boolean[]` of size 65536 to see which characters you've got:

```
public static boolean uniqueValues(char[] values) {
    boolean[] seen = new boolean[65536];
    for (char c : values) {
        int index = c;
        if (seen[index]) {
            return false;
        }
        seen[index] = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

For small arrays, this will be hugely wasteful of memory - for larger arrays (of distinct elements, or where the duplicate occurs late) it's more space efficient than the `HashSet` approach.

Comment: It's probably simpler (and more efficient!) to use a `BitSet` than a `boolean[]`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: More efficient I can buy. I reckon the complexity/readability is about the same - and I don't need to look up the API for arrays ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can test if a variable is from certain type using `instanceof` operator:

```
if (myVar instanceof Set) {
    System.out.println("It's a Set.");
    //do what you want/need
}
```

Still, the usage of `instanceof` operator seems to be a problem in your design. Even more, you must not use `instanceof` operator in an array to check if it is a `Collection`.

---

EDIT: Based on your last comment in your question, you want to seek if there's a duplicated element in your array. You can do this using the `Set` as explained in [JonSkeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17917585/1065197) (no need to rewrite the logic and explanation he already has provided).

Answer (score 0):

If your thinking of using "generics" for types the system may have List for the type it can store to check for Set you can use "instanceof" test operator in a comparison.

```
List<Object[]> alist = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
//setup the list of arrays
if(alist.get(0) instanceof Set){
// do what you do with a set
}else{
// do what you require
}
```